# Resample function for Pandas Panel with nominal data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, panel, resampling

I created a `Panel` construct from `Pandas` with `Python` (see code). After that I generalized (sum) the time with the `resample()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time_rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '31/1/2000', freq='D')
PanelData = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(3, 31, 6),
                 items=['Fish', 'Meat', 'Vegetables'],
                 major_axis=time_rng,
                 minor_axis=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

Data request:

```
PanelData
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 31 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Fish to Vegetables
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to 2000-01-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: a to f

PanelData.resample('W', how='sum', axis=1)
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 6 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Fish to Vegetables
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-02 00:00:00 to 2000-02-06 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: a to f
```

How can I generalize the `Minor_axis` with a given list (a=>Zone 1, b=>Zone 1, b=>Zone 2, etc.) that the PanelData will look like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 31 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Fish to Vegetables
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to 2000-01-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Zone 1 to Zone 3

zones = ['Zone 1', 'Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3', 'Zone 1', 'Zone 2']
```

NOTE: I'm using `Python v.2.7.6` and `IPython Notebook v.2.1.0`.

Comment: Do you just want to rename the labels in Minor_axis (a -> Zone 1, b -> Zone 1, c -> Zone 2, etc)? What has this to do with the resample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about my interrogation. It's more an issue for the `groupby()` function. I found the solution I asked for.

```
zones = ['Zone 1', 'Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3', 'Zone 1', 'Zone 2']

PanelData.groupby(zones, axis=2).sum()
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 31 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Fish to Vegetables
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to 2000-01-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Zone 1 to Zone 3
```